Can I exert simple Three.js stencil-coloring while clipping a GLTF-object with coded mesh?
While taking offset in this Three.js stencil example, ...
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=clip#webgl_clipping_stencil

that uses a coded torus mesh, and clipping planes, I need to go a step further.
As such I wish to expand my clipping-example, by means of a coded BoxGeometry, that clips GLTF.

Found this example:
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/stencil-clipping-gltf-weird-backfaces/41936/3

but it only shader-codes the clipping.

Have tried this:
https://www.amfibios.dk/TJS_Renw/three.js-master/examples/occludeClip_StackOverflowQ.html
Works - slide downwards to watch how.
I need a full moveable BoxGeometry to exert clipping. I am looking for a solution, that colors the area, where BoxGeometry clips imported GLTF-file.
